# How do I connect to PostgreSQL without specifying a database name?

Tags: php, postgresql

I need to connect to some PostgreSQL server providing some credentials, and print a list of available databases on that host for a given user.

I am trying:

```
<?php
    $connection = pg_connect("host=localhost user=testuser password=123 connect_timeout=5");
?>
```

And I get:

```
Warning: pg_connect() [function.pg-connect]: Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: database "testuser" does not exist in /var/www/test.php on line 56
```

I thought this must be possible because phpPgAdmin does it, but I looked at phpPpAdmin sources and found that they connect to a database named `template1`.

From http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/manage-ag-templatedbs.html:

> CREATE DATABASE actually works by copying an existing database. By
>   default, it copies the standard system database named template1. Thus
>   that database is the "template" from which new databases are made. If
>   you add objects to template1, these objects will be copied into
>   subsequently created user databases. This behavior allows site-local
>   modifications to the standard set of objects in databases. For
>   example, if you install the procedural language PL/pgSQL in template1,
>   it will automatically be available in user databases without any extra
>   action being taken when those databases are made.

Is there a way to connect without specifying any database?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You **have to** connect to a database. Which database you could use for a "maintenance database" depends on the installation and the subsequent administration. After a default installation there are 2 databases that could be used for the initial connection - "template1" and "postgres". It's wise to create a new user and a database with the same name and use those.

Comment: If you need to create the database, you can use the `createdb` statement in the command-line. You'll just need to pass your access credentials as parameters.

Comment: BEWARE! It's a bad idea to use ```template1``` for initial connection, because it's supposed to be used as default template for new databases creation. If there are active connections to this database — no one can create new databases.

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy we still can create database with `CREATE DATABASE somedb TEMPLATE template0`

Comment: `createdb zzz`; `psql -d zzz -U victoria`; `\l`; `\c <desired db, or create new db in psql shell>`. Use `dropdb zzz` if you later want to delete it, or leave it as a default, "dummy" db for psql connections.

Answer (score 22):

Why don't you connect to your Maintenance DB (usually `postgres`?). I don't know if that'll work. But I believe you'll have to query this database anyway to retrieve the databases available to a given user.

Answer (score 6):

As the [manual of pg_connect](http://php.net/pg_connect) says the dbname parameter in the connection string defaults to the value of the user parameter. That's why it uses 'testuser'. If you want dbname to be empty, try `"... dbname='' ..."`.

Comment: if I do so, the error is the same. PostgreSQL still tries to connect to database 'testuser'...