# Postgres: how to disconnect without logging out?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Using psql, how can I disconnect from an established connection without logging out?

To be more specific: Assuming the database server runs on localhost, I connect to the db server using

```
psql -U <user>
```

after that I am in the PSQL console. From there I can connect to one of the databases using

```
<user>=# \connect <database>
```

Now here is the question: How can I disconnect from this session without logging of from PSQL Console? I tried `\disconnect` but without any luck and using `\q` not only closes the session but kicks me out of PSQL entirely.

So is there a command which allows me to disconnect from one database and to reconnect to another database (using `\connect <another_database>`) without logging of from/ shutting down PSQL?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963348/how-to-disconnect-from-a-database-and-go-back-to-the-default-database-in-postgre

Answer (score 1):

According to the POSTGRESQL docs at [Postgres Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html), there is no meta command which will only close the current connection (without closing the PSQL application using `\q`). The only way to close the current connection is to connect to another database using `\connect`, as described in the docs mentioned above:

> If the new connection is successfully made, the previous connection is closed.

Similiar information is also provided in the second answer to [How to Disconnect from a database and go back to the default database in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963348/how-to-disconnect-from-a-database-and-go-back-to-the-default-database-in-postgre) (thanks to @Barbara Laird for pointing this out)