# How scan all databases in postgreSQL?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

It's possible to scan all databases in PostgreSQL like in MySQL, because in MySQL i can write connection like `"jdbc:mysql://" + hostName + ":" + portNumber";` and i will retrieve all schemas, but when I'am trying to do it with Postgre SQL i have not result up to time when i give the database name in url?

Comment: No, you need to connect to a [database that exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4483139/2541560).

Comment: But there is also a database that lets you see what all the databases are - you connect to it and query [sorry it's late and tired - I can find it tomorrow].

Comment: @MrR calm down. It's all described in the link I gave. If you're talking about [pg_database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-database.html), then yeah you can query that (table, not database), once you can connect to an existing database on the server.

Comment: @Kayaman - sorry - my eyes missed the link (which I can see now I hold the eyes open)...

Comment: so @Kayaman I can take tables from all databases on the server or from just one which i am connected?

Comment: What MySQL calls a "database" is in fact a _schema_. So you would map MySQL "databases" to Postgres schemas. And once you did that you can simply connect to the database where you created all the schemas. And then you can query `information_schema.schemata` to list all schemas inside that database.

Comment: OOO it's interesting thing, so can you tell me how to map MySQL schemas into PostreSQL and the question is, can I do it to the opposite direction?